# С++ код, выполняющий подключение к удалённому серверу - базе данных

Tags: база-данных, клиент-сервер, c++

Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на исходник клиента, выполняющего подключение к удаленному серверу, где находится база данных. На С++ или ассемблере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает информации - что за СУБД, под что пишем на С++.
Существует универсальное решение для большинства СУБД - ODBC. Необходимо иметь драйвер ODBC для своей СУБД. Подробнее - [ODBC (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s9ds2ktb.aspx)